# Minizinc for cycle index

Tags: function, for-loop, matrix, minizinc

I'm trying to make a MiniZinc function that return of the index value of the current visited row in a matrix but I can't figure it how, I'm pretty new to MiniZinc so the code could contain some errors.

The code would be like this:

```
function int: to_Index(array[totVert][4] of int: matrix, int: pid, int: vert, set of int: TOT_VERT) = 
forall(int: i in TOT_VERT) 
   (if matrix[i][0] == pid /\ matrix[i][1] == vert then 
    % here I would return the current value of i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that might work, depending on how the data is structured. The main hint is to use `exists` instead of `forall` since you are looking for a value. Note that this is completely untested since there in no test data.

```
function var int: to_index(array[int,int] of int:matrix, int:pid, int:vert, set of int: TOT_VERT) =
  let {
      var TOT_VERT: ix;
      constraint
      exists(i in TOT_VERT) (
               if matrix[i,0] = pid /\ matrix[i,1] = vert  then
                  ix = i
               endif
            );
     } in ix
;
```

Note: I also corrected the syntax for `matrix`.